# focus on link spanning entire width in Firefox - css

Tags: css, focus, accessibility

When tabbing or setting focus on the right arrow on homepage slider and the play and pause button the focus spans the entire width in Firefox. Working fine in Chrome and hoping to get same functionality in FF too. Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Feel free to [check out staging site here](http://mc2.cccedplan.org/)

Comment: Can you please add the relevant (and simplified) html and css code snippets for the stage container and arrow elements to your question? Have you tried to use position absolute for the arrows? (parent stage container should then have position relative)

Comment: As you tagged your question with "accessibility": I visited your website on a tablet with 1024px view width, the left arrow is overlapping the text, the right arrow is hard to see (depending on the image background the contrast is low, maybe you could add a white border or shadow to the arrow) and the play/pause icons are too small to use it with fingers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little digging (forcing the "next" link to keep `:focus`) I reckon it's the `text-indent`:

```
.bx-wrapper .bx-controls-direction a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -16px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

There's also a similar rule in line 145.

If you have access to change the HTML and CSS I'd remove the text-indent rules. Next, wrap the text you don't want displayed in a span with a class and use the same method that Yahoo uses to [visibly hide the text](https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/tenydnblog/clip-hidden-content-better-accessibility-53456.html), e.g.,

```
<a class="bx-next" href=""><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
```

CSS:

```
.sr-only {
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
```

I tried it locally in FireFox on the "Next" link and it seemed to work, but let me know if it doesn't.

EDIT: I've removed the IE6/7 version of `clip` on the assumption you're not supporting browsers that old.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like those links need a `display:inline` or inline-block. (Edit, this was meant to be a comment)

Comment: Well they are indeed spanning the entire width, meaning they are either default block level elements, or there is CSS specifying they become block level and/or 100% width. Have you tried giving them explicit fixed widths?

Comment: Hmmm. Then, as you're tabbing to these elements, have they got a tab-index attribute per chance?

Comment: I wish I was in front of my machine so could st least inspect your code

Comment: no `tab-index` currently set. Feel free to browse code when you are able to get to a computer.